# YouTube connected to the wrong Google+ page

Tags: youtube, google-plus-pages

Somehow my business has two Google+ pages and my business YouTube channel is connected to the wrong one. How do I switch the YouTube channel connection so it is connected to the correct Google+ page?

Answer (score 1):

You can add managers and transfer ownership of the YouTube business channel. Go on YouTube logged in as the channel in question. Clicking on the top right icon or avatar will show a list of options on the side, one of them being "Managers". On the manager page, you can add the business G+ account as a manager and transfer ownership to that account. Note that it might take two weeks to transfer ownership.